# How to print newlines in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am attempting to create a query through a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
Name:name 
ID:id 
Date of Birth:dob
```

The second `name` is a preset value that the user typed in through raw_input. Same for the `id` and the `dob`.

Here is what my current code looks like:

```
students[id] = {
    "\nName":name,
    "\nDate of Birth":dob,
    "ID":id, 
    }
```

And here's how it turns out:

```
{'\nName': 'Sample Name', '\nDate of Birth': 'Sample Birthdate', 'ID': 'Sample ID'}
```

I know you need to have /print before a string for the newline to work properly, but I'm not able to use that within the dictionary. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: Why on earth would you want newline characters in your keys?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're trying to print a dictionary and somehow have it automatically know what formatting you're after. Instead, be explicit about the formatting you require.

Let's start with some sample data:

```
d = {
    'name': 'bob',
    'dob': 'old',
    'ID': 1
}
```

Since you're preceding two of the fields with a newline, then I'll take a stab that actually you want the key/value on separate lines in a certain order (ID being first). So, let's set up a format string:

```
layout = """
    ID: {ID}
    Name: {name}
    Date of Birth: {dob}
"""
```

We're using a multi-line string here `'''` - so that we can build a template like text across multiple lines maintaining readability.

Finally, we use the layout and pass our dictionary to it, and Python will substitute `{name}` with the value in the dictionary with the key `name` (and so on...)

```
print layout.format(**d)
```

Result:

```
ID: 1
Name: bob
Date of Birth: old
```

Comment: For python 3.x, simply call `print` as a function: `print(layout.format(**d))`